# Should instance/class fields be prefixed in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, coding-style

As said in Uncle Bob's Clean Code, we shouldn't prefix class members. Although I totally agree with the arguments, talking specifically about Delphi, how would we differentiate private fields from public properties?

In Java that's not a problem, since there are no properties.

Microsoft also recommends this practice in big bold letters in their [Coding Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229012). They make the distinction by using lowercase for the private field and uppercase for the public property.

In addition to that, we don't have syntax highlight to field members like other IDEs (Free and Open Source IDEs included...)

So, should we prefix all of our fields? Or just the ones that collide with public properties?

**Edit:**

I know that the coding standard for Delphi is to prefix the fields with `F`, but that's preciselly what was stated as a bad practice in Clean Code. Does it mean that Delphi code cannot be "as clean" as code written in other languages?

Comment: Look at the class declarations in any unit which came with Delphi, for example `Classes.pas`. I'm looking, and everywhere I go Delphi its self is built with the principle of using `F` as a prefix for private fields.

Comment: As others have already written ( see this review: http://www.adampetersen.se/reviews/cleancode.htm ) Uncle Bob's Clean Code is very Java oriented and not as universally good as some would like us to believe. I would not choose it it as a Delphi coding bible.

Comment: There are two possible answers (*yes*, and *no*), and they are equally valid. Style guides disagree. This is not a question that can be definitively answered. Voting to close as **not constructive**.

Comment: @Rafael, it's probably pertinent, but it's inappropriate for StackOverflow. It calls for discussion, speculation, and opinion, and is therefore not a good fit here. See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), which specifically says so, and this meta link regarding [SO is not a discussion board](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128550).

Comment: Ok, I agree about been inappropriate for SO, I apologize. Actually before post the question I was pondering if I should post it or not, and I ended up posting because I saw the [coding-style] tag. The tag should be deleted then, if questions about that can't be asked here. Any question about coding-style will ask for a discussion in the end.

Answer (score 10):

The Delphi way is to prefix them with `F`:

```
strict private
  FField: Integer;
public
  property Field: Integer read FField;
```

(see the [Object Pascal Style Guide](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/10280#3.3).)

Comment: Yeap, that's the Delphi way. Actually that's the recommendation in their coding guideline. I do that, as it seems to be the only way. But it goes against the clean code principles.

Comment: @RafaelPiccolo: no it doesn't, only against a certain flavour thereof. Coding guidelines come in flavours and the exact rules of each don't matter as long as you agree on and stick to one. When working with Delphi you are much better off sticking to the Borland Pascal Guide, whose guidelines are well and widely known and adhered to. Sticking to those guidelines means instant recognizability for other Delphi developers. And that is exactly what a coding standard is for.

Comment: @MarjanVenema agreed. However, this rule (as many others) dates from decades ago. I'm not telling that we should change everything just because Bob Martin said that way. But software development really changed a lot though years and many new practices emerged to improve code expression. Maybe we shouldn't be writing software using such old standards anymore.

Comment: @RafaelPiccolo: I am not against changing standards, but there has to be a good reason to change something that works pretty darn well. And a standard being "old" doesn't qualify as a good reason in my book.

Comment: The fact that someone has written a coding guideline does not mean it is gospel. There can be different, equally useful coding guidelines. Most of the rules of such guidelines have grown historically. What is important is consistency.

Comment: @Rafael -- " But it goes against the clean code principles": While I bow to no man in my respect for Uncle Bob Martin, slavish adherence to Clean Code rules is unwise.   Prefix your private fields with an F like every other Delphi developer in the world.

Comment: @Nick, it's not a slavish adherence. Neither I want to invalidate something just because it's old. I just agreed with this section of the book. That makes sense to me. I was in doubt if the old standard is really the right one. (and I never wrote a code without the "F" yet)